# Dual boot freeze, keyboard disabled in grub boot screen win 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, keyboard

I installed ubuntu on my computer and it works perfectly. But from time to time, especially when i shut down my laptop and turned it on again, the screen stuck at grub boot screen. The keyboard was disabled and its icon didn't appear. I have to shut down and turn up my laptop for 5,6 times every time this happened. Sometimes, it can take me over 10 times to be able to use the arrow.

I did sometimes have to use bios to boot, but there was also times when i shut down, i can't get in bios boot options.

I did turn off secure boot but it doesn't help.

Comment: laptop or desktop? wired or wireless keyboard? If wireless/built-in, did you try a wired keyboard?

Comment: Is `FastBoot` on in the BIOS/UEFI settings? If so, switch it off and try again.